# Can MySql quietly abandon inserts where foreign key fails?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am executing `INSERT INTO Foo VALUES (a, b, c, ...)` and sometimes one of the `a`, `b`, etc does not satisfy a foreign key constraint.

In this situation, I want the insertion to be not happen and for no error to be generated.

Can I do this in a single statement, or do I have to do a separate `IF EXISTS`?

Comment: you mean the whole insert, right?

Comment: Why not include a `SELECT` in your insert statement that joins the referenced table?  This way, nothing would be return if the inner join fails.

Comment: @willOEM I don't know what you mean -- join in an insert. That makes no sense to me. Can you write it as a full answer please?

Comment: I tried INSERT IGNORE but `mysql_query` returns FALSE and I need it to return TRUE so that the error handling layer works properly.

Comment: please show the php code around the statement

Answer (score 6):

Yes, with the [ignore](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) keyword:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `foo` (...) VALUES (...);
```

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued.

On the other hand, if your concern is due to the fact you're inserting children before parents rows, you may as well DISABLE the constraints and ENABLE them after parents are inserted:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

-- do your inserts not caring about foreign keys

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

But this is only if you *know* you respect data integrity.

---

On a side note, I think worth adding this comment about [deferring constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) found in the mysql website:

> Like MySQL in general, in an SQL statement that inserts, deletes, or
>   updates many rows, InnoDB checks UNIQUE and FOREIGN KEY constraints
>   row-by-row. When performing foreign key checks, InnoDB sets shared
>   row-level locks on child or parent records it has to look at. InnoDB
>   checks foreign key constraints immediately; the check is not deferred
>   to transaction commit. According to the SQL standard, the default
>   behavior should be deferred checking. That is, constraints are only
>   checked after the entire SQL statement has been processed. Until
>   InnoDB implements deferred constraint checking, some things will be
>   impossible, such as deleting a record that refers to itself using a
>   foreign key.

We aknowledge that MySQL innoDB may as well implement this feature in the future.

Comment: I already tried INSERT IGNORE. Either way I get `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

Comment: FYI Full query is `INSERT IGNORE INTO Foo (x_id, y_id, total) VALUES (2, 115, 1) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE total=total+1`

Comment: It's returning from php's `mysql_query` with something which tests to boolean false.

Comment: I can't work out what mysql_query is returning. It's not NULL and it's not FALSE. Docs say it should be FALSE on an error of INSERT. What's going on?

Comment: It is FALSE, actually, I just read the log wrong. I need it to return TRUE because otherwise I have to break encapsulation at the error handling layer.

Comment: The error handler checks and reports all errors. This FALSE should not be considered an error, but I don't want the error checker to have to know that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control over the structure of the SQL for your insert, you can try something like this:

```
insert into Foo (a, b, c)
select
    x.a,
    x.b,
    x.c
from 
    (select
        101 as a,
        202 as b,
        'ABC123' as c
    from dual ) x
    inner join other_table y
        on x.b = y.pkid
```

In this instance, since you are performing an inner join on your data and its parent table, if the foreign key value in your data does not have a corresponding value in the primary table, nothing will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is using:

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) SELECT val1, val2 FROM table2 WHERE val3 = 123
```

When the `WHERE` part results to `false` then entire `INSERT` isn't executed. At the same time `SELECT val1, val2` can contain any sub-query you want.

In your case you'll probably check if foreign keys exist in the `WHERE` condition.

See [MySQL INSERT IF (custom if statements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854996/mysql-insert-if-custom-if-statements) for more detailed explanation.