# how to put conditions in php before inserting data in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i need mysql database to only contain 20 records per certain date and if a user tries to enter more data on a given that has 20 records already ...i want the program to refuse that entry and prompt the user for another date.i'm using php mysql

this is what i have tried

```
select count($hopeid)from clinics 
Where $date > midnight today and $date < 1159pm tonight and $hopeid =(hopeid)
if results < 20 then 

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO clinics(hopeid, date, time, appttype, newonARV,newfile,txtname)
    VALUES
('$hopeid','$date','$time','$appttype','$newonARV','$newfile','$txtname')") or die(mysql_errno());

    else {

        Echo"this date is full please choose another date";(mysql_errno();
    }
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Maybe have something check right away using a combo of Javascript and AJAX? Make a call and check to see if there are 20 records and return an alert if it is true

Answer (score 0):

You can place `WHERE` condition in your SQL query, like

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854996/mysql-insert-if-custom-if-statements?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

After executing query, test successful insertion using `mysql_affected_rows()`

```
if(mysql_affected_rows()==1){
      echo "Inserted..!";
}else if(mysql_affected_rows()==0){
      echo "this date is full please choose another date";
}else{
      echo "error:".mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: it will be better you can do code for **midnight today** and **1159pm tonight**! ... And, how can the error message **"this date is full please choose another date"** be echo-ed/printed out??

Comment: Specially for printing message they need to do some extra code, like first verify `count()` and then insert. But for that it has to execute two queries separately. I thought to make it simple. 
Moreover you can test `if(mysql_affected_rows()==1)` then its inserted, and failed otherwise

Answer (score 0):

after selecting the date call Ajax find  the number records in this date if is more than 20 records with that day  display  some message already 20 records are there in a message and add this new record to take it as  date+1  and so it is go to next date so user easily understand

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("select hopeid from clinics
WHERE " . $date . " BETWEEN '18/03/2011' AND '18/09/2011'"));
$result = sizeOf($result);
if ($result < 20){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ... bla bla ...);
    } else {
        echo "this date is full please choose another date";
    }
```

Comment: your solution is wrong because `$result` the result of `mysql_query()` NOT the **count of hopeid**

Comment: you cannot use `$result["hopeid"]` ... because `$result` is not an array with **hopeid** key

Comment: I think sizeOf is a solution

Comment: `sizeof` will return the size of array; NOT the count of **hopeid**

Comment: you are using `mysqli_fetch_array`, **mysqli**, providing the return value of `mysql_query`, **mysql**

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array` will return only **one** row of the result; NOT all the rows