# Conditional insert with multiple values

Tags: mysql

This question builds on my [**previous question on conditional inserts**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921124/conditional-insert-based-on-last-insert-id/25922099?noredirect=1#comment40579542_25922099).  The problem I'm trying to solve now, is when I have multiple `VALUES` to be inserted using the same `LAST_INSERT_ID` (which is set to `@EVENT_ID`).  With my previous C# script this is what the statement would look like:

```
INSERT INTO EVENTDETAILS (EVENT_ID, ITEMNAME, ITEMVALUE) 
VALUES (@EVENT_ID, 'SBEPN', '41420F'), (@EVENT_ID, 'Notes', 'Sent to USER2');
```

Using the same C# script modified to take advantage of the conditional insert provided in the linked question, this is what I end up with (if there's just a single set of `VALUES` it works as expected):

```
INSERT INTO EVENTDETAILS (EVENT_ID, ITEMNAME, ITEMVALUE) 
SELECT t.* FROM ( 
    SELECT @EVENT_ID, 'SBEPN', '41420F', @EVENT_ID, 'Notes', 'Sent to USER2') 
t 
WHERE @EVENT_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

**The Problem:**
Running this as-is gets an "*Error code 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)*".  Which makes sense, I'm providing six pieces of data where it's expecting three according to the table definition.  I tried providing the data in two groups of three, separated with parenthesis trying to emulate the `VALUES` clause in the original script above, as well as various other things that I couldn't get to work:

```
SELECT t.* FROM (
SELECT (@EVENT_ID, 'SBEPN', '41420F'), (@EVENT_ID, 'Notes', 'Sent to USER2')) 
t 
WHERE @EVENT_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

It's possible to have as many as half a dozen of these follow-on clauses, and they all need to use the same `LAST_INSERT_ID` (set as variable `@EVENT_ID`) so they're associated with a single parent row.

**Workaround:**  I know that I can just do multiple inserts of the data using single groups of three, EG:

```
INSERT INTO EVENTDETAILS (EVENT_ID, ITEMNAME, ITEMVALUE) 
SELECT t.* FROM ( 
    SELECT @EVENT_ID, 'SBEPN', '41420F') 
t 
WHERE @EVENT_ID IS NOT NULL;

INSERT INTO EVENTDETAILS (EVENT_ID, ITEMNAME, ITEMVALUE)     
SELECT t.* FROM (
    SELECT @EVENT_ID, 'Notes', 'Sent to USER2')
t 
WHERE @EVENT_ID IS NOT NULL;
```

**Question:**  Can I do this in a single insert statement that emulates the results from the first example where there are multiple VALUES statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
INSERT INTO EVENTDETAILS (EVENT_ID, ITEMNAME, ITEMVALUE) 
     SELECT t.*
     FROM (SELECT @EVENT_ID as e, 'SBEPN', '41420F' UNION ALL
           SELECT @EVENT_ID as e, 'Notes', 'Sent to USER2'
          ) t
     WHERE e IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: That works great, and if I have to add more clauses, I can just tack on another UNION ALL per clause (already tested to work as expected).  Thanks a lot, I appreciate the help.