# INSERT WHERE EXISTS

Tags: mysql, insert, exists

For MySQL, If I stored the userid and a token in the `user` table and only allows to insert record in another table if the supplied userid and token matches.I've tried

```
INSERT INTO product(description) 
VALUES('123') 
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM users where userid='myuserid' AND token='ABCD')
```

The following SQL statement produces error 
"check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users where userid='29')'"

However for update I can update successfully with

```
UPDATE product 
SET description='123' 
WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM users where userid='myuserid' AND token='ABCD')
```

Can any experts please help to advise.
I need the most efficient way to verify the user token is correct before doing the insert.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL INSERT IF (custom if statements)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854996/mysql-insert-if-custom-if-statements)

Answer (score 0):

Please try using a trigger instead:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tokenValidator 
BEFORE INSERT 
ON product
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF (SELECT 1 FROM users where userid='myuserid' AND token='ABCD') THEN
  INSERT INTO product(description) VALUES('123') 
END IF
```

Comment: Still getting an error. "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF (SELECT 1 FROM users where userid='29') THEN INSERT...". Understand that IF statement can only be used in storedprocedure