# INSERT only when IF-condition is true

Tags: mysql, if-statement, sql-insert

I would like to know if there is a possibility to Insert a row into a table when IF-Condition is true:

```
 SET @Value1 := '1'; 
 SET @Value2 := '2'; 
 IF(@Value2 >= @Value1) 
     THEN INSERT INTO `Table` 
     (`Row1`, `Row2`) 
     VALUES 
     ('Valuecheck', 'Second value is greater than first value');
 END IF;
```

MySQL reports an error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax, but I can't find that something is wrong. Insert should only be executed when IF-clause is true.

Comment: You can't use that form of `IF` in sql scripts, only stored procs & functions and triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6855014/4004477), the following should work:

```
SET @Value1 := '1'; 
SET @Value2 := '2'; 
INSERT INTO `table` (`Row1`, `Row2`) 
    VALUES 
    ('Valuecheck', 'Second value is greater than first value');
WHERE @Value2 >= @Value1
```

Comment: You'll need to edit; that answer does not use `VALUES`, but the answer referenced is appropriate.

Comment: How can this possibly be right and the accepted answer??  You cannot have a `WHERE` on an `INSERT`, the syntax is wrong anyway (extra `;` before `WHERE`), and the whole point of the linked (correct) answer is that it says you *must* be using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE`, not `VALUES`.  Grrrr....

Answer (score 2):

You can do an `INSERT...SELECT` and put your condition(s) in a `WHERE` clause; however, since MySQL requires a `FROM` and you are not referencing a table, you'll need to use its "dummy" table, called DUAL.

Like so:

```
SET @Value1 := '1'; 
SET @Value2 := '2'; 

INSERT INTO `Table`(`Row1`, `Row2`) 
SELECT 'Valuecheck', 'Second value is greater than first value'
FROM DUAL
WHERE @Value2 >= @Value1
;
```