# MYSQL- Insert if value is greater than or smaller than stock

Tags: mysql

I've seen this with almost the same problems as me  [MySQL INSERT IF (custom if statements)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854996/mysql-insert-if-custom-if-statements).

but I did not successfully execute this query:

```
INSERT into cart_items (product_id,product_variant_id,product_attribute_id,cart_id,quantity)
select (7,7,12,11,4)
where (select pa.stock from product_attribute as pa where pa.id = 12) > 4
```

in this case this is  (7,7,12,11,4) value of this (product_id,product_variant_id,product_attribute_id,cart_id,quantity)

**product_id: 7**

**product_variant_id :7**

**product_attribute_id : 12**

**cart_id : 11**

**quantity : 4**

in my headiSQL i got error like this :

> SQL (Error(1241) : Operand should contain 1 column(s)

**Table cart_items**

```
ID : Primary key autoincrement
product_variant_id : Foreign key
product_attribute_id : Foreign key
product_id : Foreign key
cart_id : Foreign key
quantity :int
```

**Table product_attribute**

```
ID : Primary key autoincrement
product_id : Foreign key
product_variant_id :Foreign key
size : varchar
stock : int
```

> I want to make query if cart_items **quantity** less than
>   product_attribute **stock** than insert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try selecting from the dummy `DUAL` table:

```
INSERT into cart_items (product_id, product_variant_id, product_attribute_id,
    cart_id, quantity)
SELECT 7, 7, 12, 11, 4
FROM dual
WHERE (SELECT pa.stock FROM product_attribute pa WHERE pa.id = 12) > 4;
```

I don't know if the above logic is what you actually intend to run, but it at least should run without syntax errors.

Comment: or just `INSERT .. SELECT 7, 7, 12, 11, 4 FROM product_attribute pa WHERE pa.id = 12 AND pa.stock > 4;`

Comment: @danblack I can't say that I even knew your suggestion would work (without an explicit table), but I am not surprised either way.

Comment: What is this mean ? `FROM dual`

Comment: It is optional and you may remove `FROM dual` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into cart_items (product_id,product_variant_id,product_attribute_id,cart_id,quantity)
SELECT product_id,product_variant_id,product_attribute_id,cart_id,quantity FROM product_attribute
WHERE id = ? && (SELECT stock from product_attribute WHERE id = ?) > (SELECT quantity FROM cart_items WHERE product_id = ?)
```

This makes sure that the stock amount is more than the cart quantity. Make sure the product ids match (?)

Also, I am not sure if you meant to do an INSERT from SELECT, but because you provided raw integer values in your example, I have changed it to be INSERT (columns) VALUES (values) because that's the correct format based on your example.

Comment: A `VALUES` clause cannot use `WHERE`.

Comment: Woops, total brainfart - you're right, I was thinking it was an UPDATE statement by the time I swapped SELECT to VALUES. I wonder if a 'case' query would be good for this even

Comment: A SELECT can't take a `(resultlist)`, it needs a `FROM`  statement, probably just accept Tim's answer

Comment: Yeah, but OP's issue is with the double select to compare the two values... I'm guessing he knows how to construct an INSERT / SELECT query - he only hardcoded the values as an example

Comment: this is ` (7,7,12,11,4)` values not comming from other table so i think i dont need to do like this `SELECT product_id,product_variant_id,product_attribute_id,cart_id,quantity FROM product_attribute`

Comment: I want to check before insert, first check stock in table product_attribute if the values for cart_items is mean quantity is less than stock and then if true insert it