# How do I not allow a specific value duplicating in the database

Tags: mysql, sql, unique-key

so I wanted to create column let's say master_user, so this master_user column has bit values, 0 and 1. What I wanted to achieve is to make it so that the column master_user has only one '1' value as there are only one master_user. You can have multiple '0' values but not '1'.

In SQL Server, you can do as so:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_master_user] ON [user]
(
    [master_user] ASC
)
WHERE ([master_user]=(1));
```

How do I do the same for MySQL ?

Thank you.

UPDATE : MySQL does not support Filtered Index and Conditional Index

Comment: I'd suggest reading the mysql [if operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html) documentation and checkout [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6854996/mysql-insert-if-custom-if-statements) for an example.

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to create a column pre-defined with the attribute of not allowing duplicated bit '1'.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would probably be to use `1` to designate a master user and `null` to designate a non-master. Since `null`s aren't values (they are the lack thereof), they don't participate in unique indexes, and having a simple `unique` index on the `master_user` column would do the trick.

If you absolutely must keep the 0s, you could add a generated column that substitutes 0 for `null` and make it unique, to the same effect:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  username VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
  master_user BIT NOT NULL,
  master_user_nullable BIT AS (CASE master_user WHEN 1 THEN 1 END) STORED UNIQUE
);
```